# Close button not vertically centered in bootstrap react popover

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am trying a simple popover and have added a close button, code as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';

const popover = (
    <Popover className="mt-2" id="popover-basic">
        <Popover.Title as="h3">
            Popover right
            <button type="button" class="close" style={{ width: '20', height: '20'}} aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </Popover.Title>
        <Popover.Content>
            And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
            right?
        </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
);


const PopoverTest = () => {
    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            {/* Wrap in the trigger to get the target */}
            <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={popover}>
                <Button className="mt-3 text-center">Click me to see</Button>
            </OverlayTrigger>
        </div>
        
    );
};

export default PopoverTest;
```

However the button is not centered vertically:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `mt-3` className in the Button component. It adds margin on the top by 1rem. If you still want to align the button at the center of its container or the page, consider styling the div that wraps the `OverlayTrigger` with flex.